# access input text in an iframe with chrome extension

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, iframe, google-chrome-extension, undefined

i'm developping a chrome extension that get elements from a form in the ServiceNow and validate it, as i noticed that ServiceNow uses iFrames for the forms .
When i trie to access an element in an iframe with content scripts i get undefined .

Here is my **manifest file :**

```
    {
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "my extension",
    "description": "This extension will help you .",
    "version": "1.0",
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "ico.png",
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },
    "permissions": ["http://localhost/Backend/public/Ask","storage"],
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["jquery-3.1.0.min.js","background.js"]
    },
    "content_scripts": [{
        "all_frames": true,
        "run_at": "document_end",
        "matches": ["https://mycompany.service-now.com/*"],
        "js": ["jquery-3.1.0.min.js","angular.js", "automation-api.js","mutationObserver.js", "myScript.js"]
    }],
    "web_accessible_resources": ["inject.js"]
}
```

and here is the code that returns **undefined** :

```
test=$("#gsft_main").contents().find("#sys_original.incident.number").val();
alert("the value is : "+test);
```

gsft_main is the id of the iframe and sys_original.incident.number is the id of the input that i want to get value .

the URL of the iFrame :

https://mycompany.service-now.com//incident.do?sys_id=-1&sysparm_stack=incident_list.do

Comment: You're using `all_frames` so your content script might be inserted in the iframe automatically and you can use messaging to send the inner element's value. Anyway, it might be a good idea to include the iframe html in the question.

Comment: @wOxxOm where to include it ?

Comment: @wOxxOm i've done it.

Comment: This is a normal iframe that should have your content script injected (look in devtools - sources panel - content scripts on the left), you may check this with `console.log(location.href)` as the first line in the content script. So the idea from my first comment should work.

Comment: Actually, `undefined` result should happen in the content script that is injected in the iframe. But then it's not clear why you need `all_frames` and the easiest solution would be to just remove it.

Comment: i tried to remove all_frames , i get the same result undefined , i even added the url of the iframe in the permissions

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121559/discussion-between-lizinh-and-woxxom).